# Download xls in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like the browser to show that the xls file has been saved. How to do it? In the example code below: it saves my Report in the correct path, but the browser does not show that the file has been saved. When I cliced button "Download report" return me empty page and not download report.

```
       public ActionResult FilePathResult(List<PrintOutModel> printOutModelList )
    { 
        Prints.Print.PrintReport.Printer print = new Prints.Print.PrintReport.Printer();
        var printReport  = print.CreateRender(printOutModelList);
        byte[] reportResult = printReport;

        string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory +"Report9802.xls";

        var fileStream = new FileStream(path,
                                            FileMode.Create,
                                            FileAccess.ReadWrite
                                        );
        fileStream.Write(reportResult, 0, reportResult.Length);


        return new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "application/xls");

    }
```

Any help or sugestion is welcome

Comment: What is your front end? Angular, Javascript, etc?

Comment: What is referencing FilePathResult()?

Comment: I use asp.net MVC 4 and Razor in View

Comment: Hi @k_dadun, How do you intend to call this MVC Action from the front-end? I mean who / what invokes this action?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are talking about browser, I am assuming your API implementation is all good and the question is front-end focussed.

Here is an example code for Angular 7. In order to download a file, your API "must" be a POST call. That is how browsers can request for a file download. You should basically be calling the postBlob method on a service, which obviously has the `HttpClient` injected as a member named `http` in this example. Because this code reads the content disposition sent by the server and sets the dynamic link, it creates an effect of user clicking a hyperlink to an XLS file and invokes the browser's default download behaviour (prompt a "save as", open automatically, etc).

Hope this helps !!

```
public postBlob(url: string, param: any): Observable<BlobFile> {

    return this.http.post<Blob>(url, param, { observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob' as 'json' }).pipe(map(r => {
        return this.onBlobResponse(r);
    }));
}

private onBlobResponse(r: HttpResponse<Blob>) {
    const contentDisposition = r.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
    const filename = contentDisposition.split(';')[1].split('filename')[1].split('=')[1].trim();

    this.saveFile(filename, r.body);
    return <BlobFile>{
        name: filename,
        blob: r.body
    };
}

private saveFile(filename: string, blob: Blob) {
    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
    } else {
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = filename;
        a.click();
        setTimeout(() => {
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            document.body.removeChild(a);
        }, 0);
    }
}
```